# Printing arrays on single line in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a 'histogram' in java and running into trouble with some formatting. I've got the below loop for printing a frequency distribution table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char asterisk[] = new char[frequency[i]];
        Arrays.fill(asterisk, '*');
        System.out.println(asterisk);
        freqTable = bins[i] + "\t";
        System.out.println(freqTable);
    }
```

But this produces an output like:

```
************
1-10    
**********
11-20   
**********
21-30
```

And i'd like to have it print like this:

```
1-10 ************
11-20 **********
21-30 **********
```

No idea how to get it to do this! Tried using toString(), didn't get anywhere though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do `System.out.print(freqTable)` before `System.out.println(asterisk)` (notice `print` and `println`).

Comment: Just a detail, `char[] asterisk` is preferred over `char asterisk[]`. The latter is the C syntax and is seldom used in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-order the statements that print your items. I would recommend using a single `println` at the end of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    char asterisk[] = new char[frequency[i]];
    Arrays.fill(asterisk, '*');
    System.out.println(bins[i] + "\t" + asterisk);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the order and using `print` instead of `println`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    char asterisk[] = new char[frequency[i]];
    Arrays.fill(asterisk, '*');
    freqTable = bins[i] + "\t";
    System.out.print(freqTable);
    System.out.println(asterisk);
}
```

or alternative use `System.out.printf`

```
System.out.printf ("%s %s%n", freqTable, asterisk);
```

or a single `System.out.println`

```
System.out.println(freqTable + asterisk);
```